# Need full access to ext4 file system from Windows 10

Tags: windows, ext4

I am looking for a method to read/write an ext4 partition from a Windows 10. Both partitions are on the same physical hard drive on a dual boot system. That means, that NFS wouldn't be sufficient. Are there open tools to achieve that?

Cheers, Jens

Comment: If you need this access from Windows rather than from Unix/Linux, then this Stackexchange site is probably not the best fit, because any answer requires knowledge on Windows, which isn't to be expected from here. https://superuser.com/ would fit better (but if you choose to ask there, please delete it here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any FOSS drivers that work with recent versions of Windows 10/11.

- There are [claims](https://atkdinosaurus.wordpress.com/2023/03/11/how-to-use-ext4-filesystems-in-windows/) that `ext2fsd` still works, but it stopped working reliably for me several years ago and I wouldn't want to trust it with my data.
- There are commercial offerings such as the [one from Paragon](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/). I've not used this at all.
- Finally some people say that you can boot WSL and [share a mounted filesystem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/access-linux-filesystems-in-windows-and-wsl-2/) back to Windows. I've not tried this but it seems hopeful